# Copy constructor called many times when data is inserted in vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class base
{
    int x;
public:
    base(int k){x =k; }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }

    base(const base&)
    {
        cout<<"base copy constructor:"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    vector<base> v;
    base obase[5]={4,14,19,24,29};
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(obase[i]);
    }

}
```

When data is inserted into vector, copy to that data goes to vector using the copy constructor.

When i run this  program,

1. for the first insertion  (i=0), one time copy constructor is called.
2. for the second insertion  (i=1), two times copy constructor is called
3. for the third insertion  (i=3), three times copy constructor is called
4. for the fourth insertion  (i=3), four times copy constructor is called
5. for the fifth insertion  (i=4), five times copy constructor is called

Please any one can tell me why this is happening? For each insertion, shouldn't the copy constructor be called only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `v` needs to resize its internal buffer, it will usually allocate a totally fresh memory area, so it needs to copy all the objects that were previously in the vector to the new location. This is done using regular copying, so the copy constructor is invoked.

You should call `reserve()` on the vector to reserve storage upfront if you can estimate how many elements you are going to need.

Note that the resize/growth behaviour of `std::vector` is implementation-dependent, so your code sample will produce different results with different standard library implementations.

Comment: Please can you also explain why in the copy constructor i need  const ketyword? if i dont use it , it gives a compilation error?

Answer (score 7):

calls to `push_back()` increase the size of the vector as necessary, which involves copying of vector's contents. Since you already know that it's going to contain five elements, either `v.reserve(5);` right before the loop, or use the range constructor:

```
base obase[5]={4,14,19,24,29};
vector<base> v(obase, obase+5);
```

Comment: Another workaround is to use `std::deque<>` instead of `std::vector<>` if contiguous memory layout isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

Your copy constructor is flawed, you forgot to actually copy the data :)

```
base(const base& that) : x(that.x)
{
    cout << "base copy constructor\n";
}
```

Also, if you have a modern compiler, you can write a move constructor and learn something new:

```
base(base&& that) : x(that.x)
{
    cout << "base move constructor\n";
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Please can you explain also why " const " needs in copy constructor. if I don't use it it gives a compilation error.

Comment: @Alok: Because references to non-const do not bind to rvalues. If this sounds too technical to you, don't worry. In practice, all copy constructors have the const, because they only *read* from the source and do not *modify* it. There would be no point to remove the const.

Comment: Thanks a lot , very nice description